# How to add columnname to value in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table that contains 3 "code" fields.  some of these fields are used to look up against a code table.  Assume the table looks like this:

```
data table:
    id    code1    code2     code3     data1
    1       Y        3         A        IA
    2       Y        2         B        IB
    3       N        5         C        IC
```

in order to perform the lookup, I have to concat the field_name to the value, delimited by a colon.  I cannot hardcode the column name.  using big query, is there a way to use the table object to infer the column name within the select statement?

for example:

```
select * from code_table join data_table where code1 = code.code_values 
the value of code1 coming out is 'code1:Y'  not 'Y'.
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to inject the column_name dynamically in the code1 value as it's going out to the code_table.

UPDATE 1:

Here's an example output from data_table to join against code_table:

```
1, code1:Y, code2:3, code3:A, IA
2, code1:Y, code2:2, code3:B, IB
3, code1:N, code2:5, code3:C, IC
```

Thanks

Comment: can you clarify - what do you mean by " I cannot hardcode the column name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does using the `TO_JSON_STRING` function give the desired output? Here is an example using your data:

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Y' AS code1, 3 AS code2, 'A' AS code3, 'IA' AS data1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Y', 2, 'B', 'IB' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'N', 5, 'C', 'IC'
)
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS json
FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t;
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| json                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| {"id":1,"code1":"Y","code2":3,"code3":"A","data1":"IA"} |
| {"id":2,"code1":"Y","code2":2,"code3":"B","data1":"IB"} |
| {"id":3,"code1":"N","code2":5,"code3":"C","data1":"IC"} |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you want to strip out the quotes, you can do that too:

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Y' AS code1, 3 AS code2, 'A' AS code3, 'IA' AS data1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Y', 2, 'B', 'IB' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'N', 5, 'C', 'IC'
)
SELECT REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '"', '') AS json
FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t;
+-----------------------------------------+
| json                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
| {id:1,code1:Y,code2:3,code3:A,data1:IA} |
| {id:2,code1:Y,code2:2,code3:B,data1:IB} |
| {id:3,code1:N,code2:5,code3:C,data1:IC} |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Edit: this gives the exact desired output. I'm assuming that you are okay with referencing `id` and `data` by name since it sounds like you don't want to format them in the same way.

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Y' AS code1, 3 AS code2, 'A' AS code3, 'IA' AS data1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Y', 2, 'B', 'IB' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'N', 5, 'C', 'IC'
)
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    FORMAT(
      '%d %s %s',
      id,
      REGEXP_REPLACE(
        TO_JSON_STRING(
          (SELECT AS STRUCT t.* EXCEPT (id, data1))
        ),
        '["{}]', ''),
      data1
    ),
    r'[ ,]', ', '
  ) AS output 
FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t;
+----------------------------------+
| output                           |
+----------------------------------+
| 1, code1:Y, code2:3, code3:A, IA |
| 2, code1:Y, code2:2, code3:B, IB |
| 3, code1:N, code2:5, code3:C, IC |
+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: I got there, I'm putting an update of what I'm looking for

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME!!!  this helps much.  Is there anyway to split output to the columns as defined by the table?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you name `code1`, `code2`, etc. explicitly as part of the query. If we had support for [templated UDFs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905991) (consider starring/upvoting the feature request) then I have an idea of how it could work.

Comment: ok.  Thanks much.  I'll see if I can look those up.  Most appreciated.

Comment: hey, can I reverse the question.  can you extract ONE field with the column-name?

Comment: for example, if I have a 50-column table, and only need one of them to do so?  Thanks.

Comment: Please post a separate question instead.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Y' AS code1, 3 AS code2, 'A' AS code3, 'IA' AS data1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Y', 2, 'B', 'IB' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'N', 5, 'C', 'IC'
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  MAX(IF(col = 1, val, NULL)) AS col1,
  MAX(IF(col = 2, val, NULL)) AS col2,
  MAX(IF(col = 3, val, NULL)) AS col3,
  data1
FROM `project.dataset.table` AS t, UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"|{|}', ''))) AS val WITH OFFSET col
WHERE col BETWEEN 1 AND 3
GROUP BY id, data1
ORDER BY id
```

output as below

```sql
id  col1        col2        col3        data1    
1   code1:Y     code2:3     code3:A     IA   
2   code1:Y     code2:2     code3:B     IB   
3   code1:N     code2:5     code3:C     IC
```

with above query you just need to know number of code columns so if it is 5 (for example) you need to add two more in `SELECT` and change `BETWEEN 1 AND 3` to `BETWEEN 1 AND 5`

Comment: Hi Mikhail.  thanks again for your genius.  How do I map the col numbers in `MAX(IF(col = ?....` to the columns?  does `col=1` mean second column (starting with zero?). thanks!

Comment: that is correct!  col=1 mean second column (starting with zero)